# What is Out(G-mod) for a finite group G?

Tags: qa.quantum-algebra, fusion-categories, morita-equivalence, outer-automorphisms

Following the notation of [Etingof-Nikshych-Ostrik](http://arxiv.org/abs/0909.3140) what is Out(G-mod) for a finite group G?

That is what are all bimodule cateogries over the fusion category G-mod of complex G-modules which have the property that they're just G-mod as a left (resp. right) G-module up to equivalence of bimodules?  I think this is the same as the group of tensor autoequivalences of G-mod which do not come from conjugating by 1-dimensional objects, but ENO only prove that in the case where there are no 1-dimensional objects.

If you have an automorphism of the group G then you get an automorphism of G-mod.  I'm not totally sure though if outer automorphisms of G necessarily give outer automorphisms (for example could you have an outer automorphism that fixed all conjugacy classes?) and I also don't know whether all outer automorphisms come up this way.

The reason that I'm asking is that I want to understand the relationship between Out(C) and Out(D) where C and D are Morita equivalent fusion categories.  However, I realized I don't have enough examples where I understand what Out(C) actually is.

Comment: Nontrivial outer automorphisms can fix all conjugacy classes. See the 1947 paper by G.E. Wall (http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=25461) for examples. Wall says that such examples were first given by Burnside in 1912, but that paper is apparently too old to appear on MathSciNet.

Comment: The 1912 Burnside paper is reviewed (in German) here: https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A43.0198.02, and the paper itself is here https://doi.org/10.1112/plms/s2-11.1.225

Comment: Title of the Burnside paper [referenced](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32063/what-is-outg-mod-for-a-finite-group-g#comment71988_32063) by @EvanJenkins and [linked](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32063/what-is-outg-mod-for-a-finite-group-g#comment1068167_32063) by @‍DavidRoberts:  [On Some Properties of Groups Whose Orders are Powers of Primes](https://doi.org/10.1112/plms/s2-11.1.225).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The group $\operatorname{Out}(G\operatorname{-Mod})$ is equivalent to the group $\operatorname{Aut}_{\textbf{Tw}}(k[G])$ of gauge equivalence classes of twisted automorphisms of the Hopf algebra $k[G]$ defined by Davydov in [*Twisted automorphisms of Hopf algebras*](https://arxiv.org/abs/0708.2757). In Davydov's other paper, [*Twisted automorphisms of group algebras*](https://arxiv.org/abs/0708.2758), he describes this group in the case that $\lvert G \rvert$ is relatively prime to 6. (The proposed description I gave in the earlier version of this answer fails in general because $\operatorname{Out}(G)$ is not in general a normal subgroup of $\operatorname{Aut}_{\textbf{Tw}}(k[G])$.)

First, we note that since $G\operatorname{-Mod}$ is symmetric, any inner tensor autoequivalence is automatically tensor equivalent to the identity, so it suffices to describe the group of isomorphism classes of tensor autoequivalences. Let $\omega: G\operatorname{-Mod} \to \operatorname{Vect}$ be the usual fiber functor. Any tensor autoequivalence $F: G\operatorname{-Mod} \stackrel{\cong}{\to} G\operatorname{-Mod}$ gives a new (tensor) fiber functor $\omega \circ F: G\operatorname{-Mod} \to \operatorname{Vect}$. This gives $G\operatorname{-Mod}$ the structure of the category of representations of some Hopf algebra; it is shown in the paper [*On families of triangular Hopf algebras*](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0110043) by Etingof and Gelaki that this Hopf algebra will be a twist of the original one, and thus $F$ induces a twisted automorphism of $H$. Conversely, any twisted automorphism of $F$ gives rise to an autoequivalence of $G\operatorname{-Mod}$. Natural transformations of monoidal functors correspond to gauge equivalences of twisted automorphisms. Thus, we can identify isomorphism classes of monoidal autoequivalences of $G\operatorname{-Mod}$ with gauge equivalence classes of twisted automorphisms of $k[G]$.